# Response from API returns data, state is undefined - React.JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a REACT component:

```
import React from 'react';
import Weather from '../service/weatherAPI.js';

export default class DisplayWeather extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      weatherData: []
    }

    this.getWeatherData = this.getWeatherData.bind(this);
  }

  componentDidMount(){
    this.getWeatherData();
  }

  async getWeatherData(){
    let data = await Weather(this.props.location)
    this.setState({ weatherData: data});
    console.log(this.state.weatherData)
  }
```

This function references a function exported from another file which is using fetch to call an endpoint. All the data returns correctly from the endpoint I am calling. However, when trying to set this data onto the state, my data is undefined.

Below is my API call, just in case I have missed anything here:

```
const Weather = (location) => {
      fetch(url, {
        Method: 'GET',
        headers : {
            'Accept': 'application/json'
          },
      })
      .then((raw) => raw.json())
      .then((response) => {
        return response
      })
    }

export default Weather;
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You have to use promises for yuor fetch function

Comment: Did the request go through when you check the network logs?

Comment: You need to transform response and assing it to your state

Comment: can you show full code example?

Comment: @wentjun Yes I got the response I expected.

Comment: @RTW I have updated it, there isnt much else to show.

Comment: @JoshuaRDBrown did you return the fetch method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to return the promise like this in your weather function:

```
const Weather = (location) => {
  return fetch(url, {
    Method: 'GET',
    headers : {
        'Accept': 'application/json'
      },
  })
  .then((raw) => raw.json())
  .then((response) => {
    return response
  })
}
```

That way the await is working on the promise instead of just the function.